# Sum Values from Ajax Request with Conditions

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an Ajax Request that pull data in difference databases, for example, I have 2 database, I make an ajax request that will query on those two database which will return,

```
[{"question_id":31,"columnheader":"joene_001","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.2","revenue":"2.4"},{"question_id":32,"columnheader":"joene_001_1","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"0","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":33,"columnheader":"joene_001_2","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.6","revenue":"3.2"},{"question_id":34,"columnheader":"TEST_001","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"1","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"10"},{"question_id":35,"columnheader":"TEST_001_1","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"2"},{"question_id":36,"columnheader":"TEST_001_2","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"2"},{"question_id":37,"columnheader":"TEST_001_3","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"4"},{"question_id":38,"columnheader":"Diabetes_UK_3147","ct_yes":"4","ct_no":"1","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"16"},{"question_id":39,"columnheader":"index_001","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"4"},{"question_id":40,"columnheader":"index_001_1","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"2"},{"question_id":41,"columnheader":"index_001_2","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"4"},{"question_id":42,"columnheader":"index_001_3","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"3","revenue":"6"},{"question_id":43,"columnheader":"index_001_4","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"8"},{"question_id":44,"columnheader":"index_001_5","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"10"}]  

[{"question_id":36,"columnheader":"TEST_001_2","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":37,"columnheader":"TEST_001_3","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":38,"columnheader":"Diabetes_UK_3147","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"8"},{"question_id":44,"columnheader":"index_001_5","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":39,"columnheader":"index_001","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":40,"columnheader":"index_001_1","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":42,"columnheader":"index_001_3","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"3","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":41,"columnheader":"index_001_2","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":43,"columnheader":"index_001_4","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":31,"columnheader":"joene_001","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":32,"columnheader":"joene_001_1","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"0","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":33,"columnheader":"joene_001_2","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.6","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":34,"columnheader":"TEST_001","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":35,"columnheader":"TEST_001_1","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"0"}]
```

As you can see there two result because I'm querying on two databases. They the same columns `question_id`, `columnheader`, `ct_yes`, `ct_no`, `ct_maybe`, `costperlead`, `revenue`

What I want to do, is to sum all information with the same `question_id` . For example `"question_id":35` both exists on result 1 and 2. I want to sum the values of it's column. Then display it in a Datatables. So far I have the code to get the records in all Databases,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/customer/all", 
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result){
    var myObj = $.parseJSON(result);
    console.log(result);
        $.each(myObj, function(key,value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/callcenter/charityresponses", 
                type: 'GET',
                data: {"from" : $("#fromDateCharityRes").val(), "to" :  $("#toDateCharityRes").val(), "dbconn" : value.dbconn},
                success: function(result2){
                var myObj = $.parseJSON(result2);
                console.log(result2);
                $.each(myObj, function(key,value) {
                    console.log(value.question_id); 
                    console.log(value.columnheader);    
                    console.log(value.ct_yes);  
                    console.log(value.ct_no);   
                    console.log(value.ct_maybe);    
                    console.log(value.costperlead); 
                    console.log(value.revenue); 
                });     

            }});
        });
    }});
```

My Ajax above `ajax/customer/all` gets the total number of Database that I need to get the information to, `ajax/callcenter/charityresponses` gets the information on that Database by its database connection string which returns the above mention result. What I need is to sum the values of the same `question_id` , where should that code go and how can I do it? I already have the code to where to assign each value to render it in a datatable.

```
console.log(result2);
```

returns

```
[{"question_id":31,"columnheader":"joene_001","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.2","revenue":"2.4"},{"question_id":32,"columnheader":"joene_001_1","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"0","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":33,"columnheader":"joene_001_2","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.6","revenue":"3.2"},{"question_id":34,"columnheader":"TEST_001","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"1","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"10"},{"question_id":35,"columnheader":"TEST_001_1","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"2"},{"question_id":36,"columnheader":"TEST_001_2","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"2"},{"question_id":37,"columnheader":"TEST_001_3","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"4"},{"question_id":38,"columnheader":"Diabetes_UK_3147","ct_yes":"4","ct_no":"1","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"16"},{"question_id":39,"columnheader":"index_001","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"4"},{"question_id":40,"columnheader":"index_001_1","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"2"},{"question_id":41,"columnheader":"index_001_2","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"4"},{"question_id":42,"columnheader":"index_001_3","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"3","revenue":"6"},{"question_id":43,"columnheader":"index_001_4","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"8"},{"question_id":44,"columnheader":"index_001_5","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"10"}]  

[{"question_id":36,"columnheader":"TEST_001_2","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":37,"columnheader":"TEST_001_3","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":38,"columnheader":"Diabetes_UK_3147","ct_yes":"2","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"8"},{"question_id":44,"columnheader":"index_001_5","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":39,"columnheader":"index_001","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":40,"columnheader":"index_001_1","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":42,"columnheader":"index_001_3","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"3","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":41,"columnheader":"index_001_2","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":43,"columnheader":"index_001_4","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"4","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":31,"columnheader":"joene_001","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.2","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":32,"columnheader":"joene_001_1","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"0","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":33,"columnheader":"joene_001_2","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1.6","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":34,"columnheader":"TEST_001","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"5","revenue":"0"},{"question_id":35,"columnheader":"TEST_001_1","ct_yes":"0","ct_no":"0","ct_maybe":"0","costperlead":"1","revenue":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do the trick using jQuery's `grep()` function, So what I did is make an array then check if the `question_id` is already there, if not, put it in and if it does, update the values, so I have

```
var result = $.grep(records, function(e){ return e.question_id == value.question_id; });
var records = [];                           
if (result.length == 0) {
    records.push({
     question_id: value.question_id,
     columnheader: value.columnheader,
     ct_yes: value.ct_yes,
     ct_no: value.ct_no,
     ct_maybe: value.ct_maybe,
     costperlead: value.costperlead,
     revenue: value.revenue,
     });

} else if (result.length == 1) {
    result[0].ct_yes = parseInt(result[0].ct_yes) + parseInt(value.ct_yes);
    result[0].ct_no = parseInt(result[0].ct_no) + parseInt(value.ct_no);
    result[0].ct_maybe = parseInt(result[0].ct_maybe) + parseInt(value.ct_maybe);
    result[0].revenue = parseFloat(result[0].revenue )+ parseFloat(value.revenue);
}
```